# Capturing Elmah Generated Application Error Information for Body of Email

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, elmah

**The email servers in the web farm at my company do not allow emails to be sent from web applications.**

When my application sends an email I do it via a stored procedure running on a SQL server. Therefore, I cannot use Elmah's email generation functionality to inform the webmaster of errors which occur within my web application.

I have created an `ErrorMessage_Elmah.aspx` page which will inform the application user that an error has occurred.

In the `Page_Load` event for that aspx page I execute the email stored procedure, passing to it the recipient, subject, and body information.

As I understand it, the information Elmah has captured pertaining to the error is contained in the Elmah.axd file. I would like to capture that information and place it into the body of my email. How do I programmatically access Elmah.axd to acquire the error information for insertion into the body of my email?

Comment: Elmah stores information about the error whatever backend storage you've configured. It does not store it in the AXD. So how did you configure the back end storage? In memory, XML, SQL Server, or some other storage provider?

Answer (score 0):

I also want to send email from my web app, and there appears to be no configuration in elmah which allows for SQL stored proc to send (cannot use smtp either). I am good with how the logging occurs to the elmah tables through the given stored procedures.

This brings me to suppose the answer is to alter the stored procedure that comes with the elmah install and provide my own email routine in there. I have tested how the following XML will appear in an HTML email. It works a champ!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ELMAH_LogError]
(
    @ErrorId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @Application NVARCHAR(60),
    @Host NVARCHAR(30),
    @Type NVARCHAR(100),
    @Source NVARCHAR(60),
    @Message NVARCHAR(500),
    @User NVARCHAR(50),
    @AllXml NTEXT,
    @StatusCode INT,
    @TimeUtc DATETIME
)
AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT
    INTO
        [ELMAH_Error]
        (
            [ErrorId],
            [Application],
            [Host],
            [Type],
            [Source],
            [Message],
            [User],
            [AllXml],
            [StatusCode],
            [TimeUtc]
        )
    VALUES
        (
            @ErrorId,
            @Application,
            @Host,
            @Type,
            @Source,
            @Message,
            @User,
            @AllXml,
            @StatusCode,
            @TimeUtc
        );
    DECLARE @TmpSubject VARCHAR(80);
    SET @TmpSubject = 'ELMAH ERROR LOG ('+@Application+')';

    -- here is the good stuff:
    DECLARE @TmpDetail NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @TmpMessage NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @xml as xml;

    set @xml = (SELECT @AllXML);

    select @TmpDetail = (select x.i.value('@webHostHtmlMessage', 'nvarchar(max)') --as HTML
    from @xml.nodes('/error') as x(i));

    SELECT @TmpMessage = '<p style="color:#000; font-size:12pt; font face:arial">USER '+@User+' encountered the following error at UTC: '+cast(@TimeUtc as varchar(22))+'</p>'+char(10)+@TmpDetail;

    -- now we can send the HTML in the body of an HTML formatted SMTP email routine:
    exec dbo.spSendHTML @To='support@mycompany.com', @SUBJECT=@TmpSubject, @MESSAGE=@TmpMessage;
```